# Table header recognition using python openCV

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, ocr, python-tesseract

I'm trying to OCR some old typewriter documents that have been -carelessly - photocopied. 
Format is as follows:
Header (I guess was pre-printed ) and then the data in three columns 
[header picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cz8eu.jpg)
I need to extract 3 different parts of the image.
Intersections a-b to end of page, b-c to eop, c-d to end of page.
In fact I need positions of intersection a,b,c,d. 
Can anyone help?

Comment: Is this helpful - https://answers.opencv.org/question/63847/how-to-extract-tables-from-an-image/ ?

Comment: ...well . I am trying to implement it in python! Thank you for the hint ...